# Drawing Text Using OpenGL and Allegro 5

Tags: c++, opengl, allegro, allegro5

How can I draw 2d text using openGL and Allegro 5 in C++? I want to be able to specify a font file to load, and not have to put all the characters into an image file by hand.

Comment: -1: For being very poorly researched. You could have looked at Allegro 5's docs to get your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Allegro 5 font addon](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/a5docs/5.0.3/font.html).

Comment: Well, the text needs to be drawn with openGL. When I try to use only the allegro font add on, It messes up the openGL rendering. Is there some way I can combine these, so that openGL is the only thing drawing to the display?

Comment: @Jcubed: Maybe you should concentrate on making Allegro's font display code work, since it does what you need. If the font displaying is being corrupted, it's probably because you have done something to OpenGL's state that Allegro did not expect. You should restore OpenGL's state before using Allegro's rendering tools.